# Allow only certain formats in tinymce 4 Modern theme?

Tags: tinymce

Is there a 'modern theme' (in other words, tinymce 4) equivalent of the `theme_advanced_blockformats` option?

`theme_advanced_blockformats` allows you to limit the set of available formats by adding the following to `tinymce.init()`:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    theme_advanced_blockformats : "p,div,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,blockquote,dt,dd,code,samp"
});
```

([TinyMCE theme advanced block formats](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/configuration%3atheme_advanced_blockformats))

I know that it's possible to explicitly specify which formats are available by passing an option to `tinymce.init()`, like so:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    formats :
            bold : {inline : 'span', 'classes' : 'bold'},
            italic : {inline : 'span', 'classes' : 'italic'},
            underline : {inline : 'span', 'classes' : 'underline', exact : true},
    }
});
```

([TinyMCE formats](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/configuration%3aformats))

Unfortunately, this wants a lot of detail about the way that each format is implemented that I don't have.

Any words of advice?

Comment: Are you trying to limit formats, add new ones or both? I think you may be able to get the equivalent through the `formats` block. I believe formats available are controlled in the core in 4.x and not up to the theme.

Answer (score 5):

This is as of latest TinyMCE release (4.1.3).
Although the "block_formats" setting documents this functionality, I could only get this to work using the following:

```
   tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
      style_formats: [
       {title: 'Paragraph', block: 'p'},
       {title: 'Heading 2', block: 'h2'},
       {title: 'Heading 3', block: 'h3'},
       {title: 'Heading 4', block: 'h4'},
    ],

 });
```

This is a simple example of the [Tinymce documented custom formats](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/custom_formats.php) syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is a bit spotty right now but you can control what is a valid block as well as define default attributes for blocks using [valid elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/configuration%3avalid_elements). Declaring allowed blocks and default styles are now up to the TinyMCE core rather than the theme. `valid_elements` declares allowed blocks and `extended_valid_elements` declares default attributes for allowed blocks.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",
  valid_elements : "a[href|target=_blank],strong/b,div[align],br",
  extended_valid_elements: "img[class=myclass|!src|border:0|alt|title|width|height]",
  invalid_elements: "strong,b,em,i"
});
```

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer with the arrow under the number on the left.

Comment: sorry it's been so long. `valid_elements` appears to only limit the output of the returned HTML to a subset, not limit i.e. the formats available while editing as `theme_advanced_blockformats` did. In any case, thanks for the help!

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:block_formats

Like:

`block_formats: "Paragraph=p;Heading 1=h1;Heading 2=h2;Heading 3=h3;Heading 4=h4"`

Answer (score 0):

For Tinymce 4x, try the following:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    block_formats: 'Paragraph=p;Heading 1=h1;Heading 2=h2;Heading 3=h3;Heading 4=h4;Heading 5=h5;Heading 6=h6;Preformatted=pre',
});
```

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/configure/content-formatting/#block_formats

ben.hamelin's answer didn't work for me in v4.8.1.